# I have to maintain value of variable which is different per user session in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

> I have implemented a Policy based authorization in .net core mvc
>   application. Code:

```
  protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidUserAuthorization requirement)
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("UserAlias", context.User.Identity.Name.Split('@')[0])
        };

        var isAuthorized = this.CubeServiceManager.GetDataFromService("CheckIfAuthorized", "GET", this.ConnectionStrings.BaseAddress, parameters);



        if (isAuthorized == "true")
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }



        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

> I have added Authorize attribute at controller level which call this Async method every time. If value of **isAuthorized** is true then user is authorized.
>   But for every call to async method, service call is being made to set the value of  **isAuthorized** variable, which i want to cache per session for each user.
>   **How can i do it in this Authorization handler.?**

Comment: Logically, you cannot cache the result of this call to your service, as it's contextual. Each request needs to individually check its authorization. Otherwise, the first person that's authorized, would then effectively allow everyone else to be authorized as well, as long as the cache held out. Likewise, if it's cached as "unauthorized", then no one could become authorized as long as the cache held out.

Comment: @ChrisPratt what if i use session with a key which is unique per user?

Comment: That's safer, but still kind of poses a similar problem. Depending on how long the info is "cached", you may not be returning a correct auth status. Generally speaking, if your authorizing via a service, you should do that every request. It's not something you should ever cache.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Right ! I can do one thing, create scope of service singleton, so  that only object will server the status through out  the session

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [memcached](http://memcached.org/), also Enyim client is ported to .Net Core:
https://github.com/cnblogs/EnyimMemcachedCore